# Pycharm and bitbucket plugin

Tags: git, bitbucket, pycharm

I have installed bitbucket plufin to connect my Pycharm with bitbucket.I have tried in VCS menu in PyCharm -> import into Versions control -> Share project (with bitbucket icon) -> name it like my project -> mark that it is Git repository -> click Ok and I get then error message "Share project on bitbucket - push failed"

```
Log 11:11:33.157: cd /Users/apple/Documents/Projects/Python/Study_python2
11:11:33.157: git show --name-status -M --pretty=format:%x01%h%x02%H%x02%ct%x02%an%x02%at%x02%ae%x02%cn%x02%ce%x02%p%x02%d%x02%s%x02%b%x02%B%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 5847233
11:11:33.066: cd /Users/apple/Documents/Projects/Python/Study_python2
11:11:33.066: git log HEAD --branches --remotes --tags --max-count=340 --date-order --pretty=format:%x01%h%x02%ct%x02%p%x02%an%x03 --encoding=UTF-8 --full-history --sparse -- .
```

- I have tried to import into Versions control -> Share project on Github - and it's OK
- Also I have local .git installed in project dir

**[Update]**
After setting up my repo and initial commit I met new error in pycharm when I tried to push smth: `Push failed: fatal: The remote end hung up unexpectedly` I add my public key to bitbucket but that din't solve my problem. The solution was to connect to bitbucket via https not ssh

- Go to bitbucket and copy https link to your repo
- Edit `url` in the file in your project dir `.git/config` with https link

Comment: Hey, did my answer work for you?

Comment: Hi, try a new "jetbrains-bitbucket-connector" plugin from here:
https://bitbucket.org/dmitry_cherkas/jetbrains-bitbucket-connector/downloads

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I've faced the same problem, here is the solution:

http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=klfLSRXUOzY

The main problem here, is that no remote is added to the project by PyCharm / PHPStorm / IntelliJ. This means you have to manually add the remote via `git add remote <your remote here>`

Comment: Can you please summarise the answer here?